# Partial views in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

We are having reusable partial views with separate model associated with it. while doing post back, the partial view model is not getting populated and its returning null.

Example

```
ViewPage<ParentModel>

<%Htmlhelper.RenderPartial<controlname,ParentModel.ChildModel>
```

Please advice what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks
Subu

Comment: Need more info.  Show the controller code, how you're populating the viewmodels, does ParentModel have any data at all at the point where you're calling RenderPartial etc.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Parent model holds the child models.[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveData(TestViewModel priorProgressiveViewModel)
        {
            _TestModel.UpdateModel(testViewModel);
            validateUserInput(priorProgressiveViewModel);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _testNavigation.NavigationOff();
                return           }
            return View("Index", testViewModel);

            
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are not passing data to the partial view, so it has nothing to render as it does not know what to parse into view.